# How to fetch data from MYSQL table into Android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to fetch some data from the below table into an Android application.
I'm not sure how to handle the data transfer. I wrote a php file that should get the last record from my table and display it in a simple TextView in Android studio.

PHP part:

```
<?php
require "conn2.php";   
$mysql_query = "SELECT readTemperature FROM sensors ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
        echo "readTemperature: " . $row["readTemperature"]. "<br>";
     }      
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();  
?>
```

Android part:

```
public class TemperatureSetting extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature_setting);

    Button getTemperature = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    Button setTemperature = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setButton);
    EditText desiredTemperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desiredTemp);
    TextView currentTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureRead);
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this seems to be easy, I'm a dummy in such things.
Many thanks!

Comment: Please add all your code in your question. Screenshots are not helpful.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that...thought that screenshot would be enough, code is added now

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement an `async` task that will fetch the data from a given php file.

here is a link that can help :

> http://androidcss.com/android/android-fetch-php-without-library/

You can also do this using [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) and [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) but i suggest you to stick to the first provided link.